# Auto.Arima fits well except for a single spike

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I'm an engineering grad student and as a small part of my thesis I'm trying to analyze some groundwater data in r using the auto.arima function. The fitted functions for my data fit well except for one spike in the data and I cannot figure out for the life of me why they go off the rails here. There are no oddities or missing values in the data. The data is the elevation of the groundwater and has one recorded point per day.

My raw unfitted data looks like this:

```
#load tseries library
library(tseries)
# RESERVOIR ONLY ANALYSIS#
#Daily Piezometric Data from PS13-01
PS1301 = read.csv("PS13-01.csv",TRUE,",")
#impute missing data from data set
PS1301 = imputeTS::na_interpolation(PS1301)
#Create Time Series
PS1301 = ts(PS1301[,2],frequency = (365),start = c(2013,116))
plot(PS1301, xlab='Time', ylab = 'Piezometric Head')
```

[image]

And then after running Auto.Arima it fits this:

```
#Auto Arima of only piezometers
#PS1301
AAPS1301 = auto.arima(PS1301)
AAPS1301
summary(AAPS1301)
## Series: PS1301
## ARIMA(2,1,0)(0,1,0)[365]
## 
## Coefficients:
##          ar1     ar2
##       0.3362  0.5722
## s.e.  0.0643  0.0625
## 
## sigma^2 estimated as 0.02372:  log likelihood=2779.3
## AIC=-5552.61   AICc=-5552.59   BIC=-5536.39
plot(PS1301,col="red")
lines(fitted(AAPS1301),col="blue")
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, I'm pretty unsure as to what to do from here. I feel like this has to be an error because of how well the fit is(visually) for the rest of the time series. I'm also more than happy to provide the raw data but I am not sure how to put it in this post other than as a dropbox link https://www.dropbox.com/sh/563nu3daeid0agb/AAB6NSddVUKgBCCbQtuqXPsZa?dl=0

Comment: Can you please post your data so the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I've posted a dropbox link to the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the seasonal period is very long (365) and R is trying to fit a diffuse prior to the corresponding state space model -- which becomes increasingly difficult with very long periods. There appears to be some numerical instability as a result, giving inaccurate fitted values at the 366th and 367th observations.

I am not convinced that using a seasonal ARIMA with such a long period makes any sense, but if you want to do it, use the CSS estimation method instead of full likelihood:

```
fit_css <- auto.arima(PS1301, method='CSS')
```

It is also much faster.

Comment: Thanks, that made it much better! What would you recommend instead? auto.arima was just a suggestion from one of the members of my supervisory committee and I was going off of that suggestion to start.

Comment: See https://otexts.com/fpp2/weekly.html and https://otexts.com/fpp2/complexseasonality.html